# GaussianProductOp.ProductAverageConditional - has quality band Experimental which is less than the recommended quality band (Preview)

Tags: infer.net

I have a quite simple rule and I get already the quality band issue. Can someone explain why this is happening? I have read the docs about [Quality bands](https://dotnet.github.io/infer/userguide/Quality%20bands.html) but I don't understand it.

This is the code I wrote that produces the warning:

```
Gaussian BornYoungPerLitterDist = new Gaussian(5.5, 0);
Gaussian BirthRateDist = new Gaussian(0.004102103451, 0.00000144);

Variable<double> BornYoungPerLitter = Variable.Random<double, Gaussian>(BornYoungPerLitterDist);
Variable<double> Birthrate = Variable.Random<double, Gaussian>(BirthRateDist);

InferenceEngine engine = new InferenceEngine();
Gaussian Born = engine.Infer<Gaussian>(BornYoungPerLitter * Birthrate);
Console.WriteLine(
    "Born Mean: {0:f10}, Standard Deviation: {1:f10}",
    Born.GetMean(),
    Math.Sqrt(Born.GetVariance())
);
```

the warning is:

```
Compiling model...compilation had 1 warning(s).
  [1] GaussianProductOp.ProductAverageConditional(vdouble2_use_B, vGaussian0, vGaussian1) has quality band Experimental which is less than the recommended quality band (Preview)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered on the Github repository from Infer.Net.

On date January 2019 the feature is still in development and for that always throws the warning.

> This happens because the code that implements a product of Gaussian variables (GaussianProductOp) is in an early stage of development. If you want to disable the model compiler errors and/or the warnings, set the options on engine.Compiler.

https://github.com/dotnet/infer/issues/104